# Redirect all traffic to root to include file in path mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to figure out how to redirect all requests to:

```
http://www.i2systems.com
```

To include "index.php" in url like this:

```
http://www.i2systems.com/index.php
```

This request:

```
http://www.i2systems.com/services/supply-chain-design/
```

becomes this:

```
http://www.i2systems.com/index.php/services/supply-chain-design/
```

How can I achieve this - I have tried this, but its not working:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^i2systems.com [NC]<br>
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.i2systems.com/$1 [L,R=301]<br>
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php/.*
RewriteRule (.+) /index.php/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Since it is important to NOT to redirect when index.php is already present at the start of request URI.

**Update:** To avoid css, js redirection try this (assuming you only want */services/* path to redirect as per your original question):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/services/.*
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: When I add that, it is redirecting every instance to add index.php - so all of the embedded stylesheets/js files are getting the index.php added so the page is not rendering correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{query_string} ^(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1?%1
```